# How to fix: attempt to index nil with 'entered'

Tags: lua, roblox

So basically, the script is supposed to load text after the intro screen disappears, not sure what's wrong with it because it worked back in 2014 :/

**The Code:**

```
if true then
    script.Parent.slowsleigh:Play()
    fadegui({intro.load},{0},{1},30)
    wait(1)

    local titles = intro.titles
    local text1 = titles.title1.Text
    local text2 = titles.title2.Text
    local text3 = titles.title3.Text
    local text4 = titles.title4.Text
    if GameData.entered == 1 then
        text1 = "And you came back."
        text2 = "You can't change the past."
        text3 = "Pathetic."
    end

    titles.title1.Text = ""
    titles.title2.Text = ""
    titles.title3.Text = ""
    titles.title4.Text = ""
    --[
    titles.title1.Visible = true
    for i = 1, #text1 do
        titles.title1.Text = string.sub(text1,1,i)
        wait(0.05 + math.random(-5,10)/200)
    end
```

And heres the script inside of ServerScriptServices

```
local data = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetGlobalDataStore()
local dataVersion = 2

local func = Instance.new("RemoteFunction",workspace)
func.Name = "GetData"
function func.OnServerInvoke(player)
    local store = data:GetAsync(tostring(player.UserId))
    return store
end

local set = Instance.new("RemoteEvent",workspace)
set.Name = "SetData"
set.OnServerEvent:connect(function(player,newData)
    local store = data:GetAsync(tostring(player.UserId))
    for i,v in pairs(newData) do
        store[i] = v
    end
    data:SetAsync(player.UserId, store)
end)
```

**The Error:**

```
  17:48:57.908  Players.Trl0_P90.PlayerGui.maingui.mainscript:758: attempt to index nil with 'entered'  -  Client - mainscript:758
```

Comment: what is `GameData`?

Comment: @Kylaaa I'm not sure lmao, the only part that mentions game data is

`local GameData = workspace:WaitForChild("GetData"):InvokeServer()
local SetFunc = workspace:WaitForChild("SetData")
local SetData = function(dat)
 SetFunc:FireServer(dat)
end
`

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question for us to actually help you. If `GameData` is defined as the result of a [RemoteFunction:InvokeServer()](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/RemoteFunction/InvokeServer), then you need to find the script that handles the [OnServerInvoke event](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/callback/RemoteFunction/OnServerInvoke) for the `GetData` RemoteFunction. It should be returning a table with an entered key, but it's currently returning nothing. If you find that Script, you should update your question to include it.

Comment: @Kylaaa Ok I updated it and it now includes the code for the GetData remote function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that you are trying to access `GameData.entered`, when `GameData` is nil.

From the code you have shared, your issue appears to be that you are accessing data from the data store and not accounting for the fact that it might not exist. Take a look at the docs for [GlobalDataStore:GetAsync()](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/GlobalDataStore/GetAsync) :

> This function returns the latest value of the provided key and a DataStoreKeyInfo instance. If the key does not exist or if the latest version has been marked as deleted, both return values will be nil.

This could be caused by a new player joining, and there being no default data. So, one thing you could do is set up some default data in case there's a new player:

```
local func = Instance.new("RemoteFunction",workspace)
func.Name = "GetData"
function func.OnServerInvoke(player)
    local store = data:GetAsync(tostring(player.UserId))

    -- if there is no data, it might be a new player!
    -- provide some new player data
    if not store then
        store = {
            entered = 1,
            foo = true,
            bar = "blah",
        }
    end
    return store
end
```

This way, the function will always return the correctly shaped data.